# Create a Calendar illustration of the busiest days during the year (total) Divvy Bikes

Tags: r

I'm using the following:

```
// install.packages("tidyverse")
// install.packages("rmarkdown")
// install.packages("bookdown")
// install.packages("plyr")  #Used for merging multiple CSV's into one dataframe
// install.packages("modeest")
// install.packages("calendR")
// install.packages("readxl")
// install.packages("ggplot2")
// install.packages("ggplot")
// install.packages("dplyr")

daily_count <- divvy_data %>% 
  count(started_on) %>% 
  as.data.frame(daily_count) %>% 
  select(-c(started_on)) %>% 
  unlist(use.names = FALSE) 

scale_fn <- function(x) { x / sqrt(sum(x^2)) } # placing values within a 0-1 by ratio and to be used in the calendR

calendR(year = 2022,
        special.days = scale_fn(daily_count),
        gradient = TRUE,
        special.col = rgb(0, 0.2, .7, alpha = 1), 
        low.col = "white")
```

**It says: Error in divvy_data %>% count(started_on) %>% as.data.frame(daily_count) %>%  :
could not find function "%>%"**

Can anyone help me? Thank you!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKmTy.png)

Comment: Your code only shows the package installation and not the package loaded i.e you need `library(dplyr)` to load the package

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
daily_count <- divvy_data %>% 
  count(started_on) %>% 
  data.frame() %>% 
  select(-c(started_on)) %>% 
  unlist(use.names = FALSE)
```